# Facebook messenger webhook provide "Attachment Unavailable" instead of location coordinates

Tags: facebook, location, bots, messenger, facebook-webhooks

I'm building a messenger bot using the facebook webhook, but every time I send a location to the bot I get the following attachment without coordinates:

```
"attachments":[
   {
      "type":"fallback",
      "payload":{
         "title":"Attachment Unavailable"
      }
   }
]
```

Is there a permission somewhere to enable to allow the bot to get the coordinates ? (like privacy settings ?)

I know that the "quick replies location" is deprecated, but I'm doing standard location point sharing.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67669648/facebook-messenger-bot-attechement-unavailable-when-user-send-me-the-location) is facing the same problem as me but his question has no response ...

Thanks